# Spring Boot JPA - Entities

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, entity-relationship

Hopefully, you can help me with the following doubts that I have.

So I have an entity called User that has some columns like Nationality, Gender, Professional Status. And I have an entity for each column referred.

I'm looking for the best way to define this.

Should I apply a ManyToMany relationship between those tables? Since Users can have the same Nationality and Gender?

When I try to implement this, Spring is creating a third table automatically and I don't understand the need.

Having the following shouldn't be enough?:

**Table User:
id,
name,
id_nationality.
id_gender,
id_professional_status**

**Table Nationality:
id,
nationality**

(etc)

Why Spring is creating another table called user_nationality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when using ManytoMany it will create a weak entity table which holds the references of bot tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we are using the ManyToMany relationship in that case a separate table will be created containing both primary keys of the tables involved in the new relationship.